# Why does this Inc() and PullFilter() not work together?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

Why wont this Inc() and PullFilter() properly update my document(only the Inc() function works and updates my Count property in my document).

```
_rooms.UpdateOne(
Builders<Room>.Filter.Where(x => x.RoomId == roomId),
Builders<Room>.Update
.PullFilter(x => x.Players, y => y.UserId == userId)
.Inc("PlayerCount", -1));

public class Player
{
public string UserId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Room
{
public string RoomId { get; set; }
}
```

The result is that the array element(x.Property) is not removed as specified by mu PullFilter(). It does work with push, not sure why it wont work with pullfilter.

Comment: Can you show the definition for `Class`? And are you sure that the array element also has an id equal to the document's id?

Comment: The exact samequery works, when using Push() instead of PullFilter to add items to my array. The PullFilter() alone works fine, without including the Inc() clause.

Comment: Can you show the _definition for `Class`_? And are you sure that the array element also has _an id equal to the document's id_?

Comment: Class has an int property called Count, and a List<Player> which also has an id. The Id i pass to the function is also present in the Players I'd property.

Comment: And the `Player` you want to remove has the same id as the `Class` document?

Comment: Why can't you edit your question to show the actual definition of these? It would make this scenario so much easier for me to test and debug. See: [mcve]

Comment: I created [this demo](https://pastebin.com/eT1aigmE) and it works fine - no issues.

Comment: Ok, i fixed the question. Added class definitions

Comment: Thanks. Weird, don't understand why it won't work. The Inc() works. PullFilter only works when i run it alone

Comment: In case it's a versioning issue: I was testing against Mongo DB 3.6 (server) using the latest Mongo DB client driver (2.12.1).

Comment: I'll check it out.